# run 2 seperate cmd commands from vb forms appliaction

Tags: vb.net, forms, cmd

i want my program to open cmd , change directory and then do the command : "copy /B file1 file2 output"

this is what i have at the moment. but all that happens is a  cmd window flashes for a second  but no file gets created

```
Dim cmd1 As String
Dim cmd2 As String
    cmd1 = "cd " & FolderFromFileName(imagename)
    cmd2 = "copy /B " & NameOnlyFromFullPath(imagename) & "+" & "TEMP.txt" & " " & TextBox1.Text
    Shell("cmd /c" & " " & cmd1 & " " & cmd2, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
```

please help, thanks :)

Comment: removed "shell" tag, nothing to do with shell. read the tag-wiki of "shell"

Comment: This is a good example why you should not use Shell(), the error reporting sucks.  You need "&&" to combine two commands on one line.  Use the FileStream class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to have a command prompt appear?  You could do all this without a separate process by using the system.io library.  If you really need the cmd prompt you can create a process.

```
Dim NewProcess = New Process
' a new process is created 
NewProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
' redirect IO
' PVWCmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
'       PVWCmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
'      PVWCmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
' don't even bring up the console window
NewProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
' executable command line info
NewProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd"

NewProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\"
'        NewProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = +" > """ + "LogFile.log" + """ 2>&1"

NewProcess.Start()
```